# Secure LDAP authentication w/python3 in windows domain

Tags: python-3.x, ldap

Straight to the point: I've managed to make this script work:

```
import os
from ldap3 import Connection, Tls, Server
import ssl

tls_configuration = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
server = Server('ldap://myserver.org:389', use_ssl=True, tls=tls_configuration)
conn = Connection(server, user="DOMAIN\\"+os.environ.get( "USERNAME" ), password=pwd) # Username and password previously obtained

if conn.bind():
    print("OK LOGGED")
else:
    print("NOT LOGGED")
```

The question is: how much this approach can be considered secure?
Is there any alternative I can use in Python 3?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that’s the right way to secure an ldap connection but there are some issues in your code:

- Usually ldap uses the 636 port for the secure connection; port 389 is for cleartext. But this can be changed by the server configuration.
- You’re using TLS version 1 that is equivalent to SSL version 3 that is outdated, you should use TLS1.2 but this must be supported by your server.
- In the Tls object you specify `validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED` but you don’t pass any CA file. This means that you’re relying on the OS to validate the certificate.

So your connection is secure only if the previous issues are resolved.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately my server does not use secure connection so I had to remove the TLS configuration too.

Comment: Without TLS all messages from/to the server are easily readable, this is definitely unsecure, and can be acceptable only on a local network if you trust your environment.